# change protocol https to http of GetRedirectUrl in Forms Authentication in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, https

Using form with requireSSL = true.

in the success login im doing a

```
FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(username, rememberMe);
```

GetRedirectUrl returns for example: '/www.domainname.com/' and make it end in https://www.domainname.com/ while i want to end in http://www.domainname.com/

this is a variable ReturnUrl.

I want this to explicit change this to http instead of https.

Answer (score 0):

```
var redirectUrl = new Uri(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(username, rememberMe), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
var parts = redirectUrl.Split('?');
var builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
builder.Scheme = "http";
builder.Path = parts[0];
if (parts.Length > 1)
{
    builder.Query = parts[1];
}
string url = builder.ToString();
```